# Best practice of throwing exception native code

Tags: c#, c++11, exception, wrapper

I am building a C++ native library which is going to be called from Managed C# application.

This native library may return error_codes as values not as exception. I was wondering if there more standard way to pass exception from native to C# without encapsulating them into integers (error_codes)?

For example is there a way to throw the exception in the native and catch it in the manged side?

Comment: What kind of exception do you plan to throw?  Have you looked into `std::experimental::expected<E,T>` -- would having the API return that (or something equivalent), then the glue code convert that into an exception or an equivalent expected monad for C# consumption, do?  What are you using to glue your native C++ to your C# code?

Comment: To use native C++ in .Net, the main options are COM, P/Invoke of C API (not C++ objects), or C++/CLI.

Comment: Having to use error codes in interop code is boilerplate.  You cannot get any info out of a C++ exception.  Only shot you have is [RaiseException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The C# code should get an SEHException if you pick the exception code correctly.  Be careful to not catch the bad stuff.